# WebDAV get free space info

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webdav, yandex-api

I'm working with Yandex Disk API (http://api.yandex.com/disk/doc/dg/reference/propfind_space-request.xml).
Having trouble with adding property in the request body (**quota-available-bytes** and **quota-used-bytes**)

```
public static string SpaceInfo(string path)
{
    // Authorization.
    HttpWebRequest webReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://webdav.yandex.ru/");
    webReq.Accept = "*/*";
    webReq.Headers.Add("Depth: 0");
    webReq.Headers.Add("Authorization: OAuth " + token);
    webReq.Method = "PROPFIND";

    // Adding data in body request.
    string inputData = @"<D:propfind xmlns:D=""DAV:""><D:prop><quota-available-bytes/></D:prop></D:propfind>";
    byte[] buffer = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(inputData);

    webReq.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8";
    webReq.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
        string dinfo = sr.ReadToEnd();

        return dinfo;
    }
}
```

I don't get any response, maybe i can use another method? What should i do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quota-available-bytes should use same namespace "D"