# Bash get owncloud space size

Tags: bash, owncloud, nextcloud

Is it possible with bash to get the owncloud/nextcloud space size? 
I know there is a way in c# like this [WebDAV get free space info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705670/webdav-get-free-space-info) but I need a way with bash.
I want to use t in conky.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can access nextcloud via curl to get the webdav xml response. There you can find the space as an attribute. This is the attribute: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc4331.html 
And please use nextcloud instead of owncloud because it is actively maintained.